# Collection View in UIViewController optional unwrapping crash

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uicollectionview

Still very new to Swift and having read/learnt about "best practices", I am trying to refactor some simple code but having trouble to wrap my head around optionals and placing a simple `UICollectionView` in a `UIViewController`.

**What I have, which works**

```
class AddFriendsController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 111, height: 111)

        let collectionViewTest = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionViewTest.delegate = self
        collectionViewTest.dataSource = self
        collectionViewTest.register(UserFriendCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        view.addSubview(collectionViewTest)
        collectionViewTest.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionViewTest.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionViewTest.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionViewTest.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc private func handleCancel() {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension AddFriendsController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 9
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserFriendCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

**What I want it to be like**

```
class AddFriendsController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let cellId = "cellId"
    private weak var collectionViewTest: UICollectionView?
    private weak var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

        layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout!.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout!.itemSize = CGSize(width: 111, height: 111)

        collectionViewTest = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout!)
        collectionViewTest!.delegate = self
        collectionViewTest!.dataSource = self
        collectionViewTest!.register(UserFriendCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        view.addSubview(collectionViewTest!)
        collectionViewTest!.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionViewTest!.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionViewTest!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionViewTest!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc private func handleCancel() {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension AddFriendsController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 9
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserFriendCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

Doing this because I want to try to apply "best practices" from the start while learning Swift, i.e. from what I understood in this case make as much stuff `private` as possible and `weak`ify/"optionalize" views/outlets to avoid retain cycles.

**Problem**

App crashes because of bang unwrapping a nil at the `layout!.sectionInset` level.

Any good soul willing to enlighten me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is you layout property weak? Is it retaining the view controller? And why don't you initialise it from the declaration? So you don't need to force unwrap: `private let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're declaring you layout as weak. If you change it to strong, i.e. just remove weak then you should be ok.

Same for your CollectionView.

Also as a matter of style, you could declared your layout and your collectionView to be implicitly unwrapped rather than unwrap each time.

So something like `private var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!`

Comment: and also remove weak from collectionView, you should use weak when you make IBOutlet because this view was created and keep in storyboard / xib!

Comment: Works fine @Chris, thanks ! @Vadim ok that was my main interrogation: `weak`ify views is really only needed when designing the UI from the storyboard but not programmatically for the reason you just quoted, i.e. in my case it will be safely deallocated when nothing else points to it ? What if I have a reference to `collectionViewTest` in another controller `controllerB`: should I `weak`ify this reference in `controllerB` to avoid a retain cycle when I dismiss `controllerB` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your code.

If you are taking your variable as optional like

```
 private weak var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout?
```

Then before forcefully unwrap you should make confirm that this is non nil. So at this line it gives crash because you are trying forcefully unwrap a variable which is actually nil.

```
layout!.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

So if you want to do like it without adding non nil check than you should write.

```
layout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

But here your code is also wrong because you should not take variable weak because **A weak reference is just a pointer to an object that doesn't protect the object from being deallocated by ARC**.

Here you want UICollectionViewFlowLayout and UICollectionView through out the lifecycle of UIViewController so you should not take it as weak.

So you should define both as under .

```
    private var collectionViewTest: UICollectionView!
    private var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
```

OR

```
   private var collectionViewTest: UICollectionView?
    private var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout?
```

Comment: Thanks for the details @Nikunj

Comment: it's my pleasure :)